# What is the difference between "I thought John would go to your place" and " I thought John would've gone to your place"?

Tags: difference, tense

What is the difference between

> I thought John would go to your place.

and

> I thought John would've gone to your place.

Comment: There isn't any significant difference. _I thought John would go_ refers to the speaker's expectations before the event, 'I thought John would have gone_  expresses surprise that he didn't.

Answer (score 0):

"I thought John would have gone to your place" implies "but he didn't" or "but I was wrong".

"I thought John would go to your place" doesn't convey the idea that something might have happened but didn't.

https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-could-have-should-have-would-have/3391128.html